# Can we create human muscles artificially?

Tags: biochemistry, synthesis

Can chemical processes create sarcomeres? Not the entire cell with mitochondria, just what basically makes the muscle contract, myosin and actin, in the goal of reproducing our muscles. The source of energy and the activation of troponin could then be controlled externally.

Comment: Interesting. But I believe we aren’t that far yet.

Comment: I don’t think this question is too broad: it is very well-defined and asks about a single point of interest. I also think that it is not opinion-based: either there are papers in the literature that say ‘yes’ or there are no such reputable papers. In any case, I am voting to leave open.